# Can the magnetic field at one end of a long solenoid be calculated using Ampère's Law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

I know that at the ends of a long solenoid induced magnetic field is $B= (μ_0NI)/2$. This is found by either integration or considering it as a part of a similar long solenoid.
But my question is that is there any way of calculating the same result by Ampere's circuital law?  (Preferably without considering it as a part of longer solenoid)

Comment: Do you mean in integral form?

Comment: @BioPhysicist Yes. I'm not sure how to apply it in this particular situation

Comment: My guess is that the answer is "no", since Ampère's Law only allows you to completely derive the field in situations where there is a large amount of symmetry.  In particular, the traditional derivation of the field of a solenoid via the integral form of Ampère's Law relies on the translational symmetry of the infinite solenoid;  this is no longer present for the half-infinite solenoid.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Answers should be posted as answers, not comments. Unless you were wanting someone else to say what you are saying in an answer?

Comment: @BioPhysicist:  This is one of those questions that I'd only feel comfortable posting an answer if I could provide an affirmative answer.  Saying effectively "I doubt it, but I don't know for sure" (as I've done above) doesn't seem like a definitive enough answer to me to post it as such — other folks might be smarter than I am and know a way to do it.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert But your comment isn't asking for clarification from the OP, nor is it suggesting an improvement to the post. I agree with your comment, and I think it should be made into an answer.